# Spellcheck upper case words using WPF in Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, spell-checking

I have a WPF application with some text boxes that have `CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper` as well as `SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true`.

In Windows 7 this works fine, but in Windows 10 the words in the textbox set to `CharacterCasing.Upper` are ignored by the spellchecker. It seems to ignore upper case words in normal text boxes as well, presumably treating them as an abbreviation.

Is there some way to make the spell checking case insensitive using the built in WPF spell checking?

**EDIT:**

Fast forward over a year later. Wasn't able to find a native .NET solution, but we found and ended up using [Keyoti Rapidpell](https://keyoti.com/products/rapidspell/wpf/spell-checker.html), a 3rd party spell checking plugin. It isn't free but it worked around the issue for us.

Just had to set the following flag:

```
SpellChecker.IgnoreIncorrectSentenceCapitalization = false;
```

Would still be nice to have a way to do it without an external library of course.